# Having Trouble Implementing DLL in a C++ Program

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I am a C++ newbie and have been asked to retrieve and manipulate data from mass spectrometry equipment. I was given some DLL libraries and their documentation with which to do this. The libraries and their documentation can be found by making an account with Thermo Fisher here:

https://thermo.flexnetoperations.com/control/thmo/RegisterMemberToAccount

The software package is MSFileReader 3.0. The documentation itself can be viewed here:

http://www.thermoscientific.de/content/dam/tfs/ATG/CMD/cmd-documents/oper/oper/ms/lc-ms/soft/Man-XCALI-97542-MSFileReader-30-Ref-ManXCALI97542-A-EN.pdf

I have the 64bit version of the software. I am using MS Visual Studio Community 2015. I chose to use run-time terminology. My code is below.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    HINSTANCE hInst = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\Nathan\\C++\\GetEvenOdd\\Debug\\XRawfile2_x64.dll");
    if (!hInst)
    {
        std::cout << "\ncould Not Load the Library" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE; 
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "\nSuccess" << std::endl;
    }
    //Resolve the function address 
    FreeLibrary(hInst);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

What puzzles me is this, when the path inside LoadLibrary() is set to another DLL that I created, the program indicates successful loading; when I try to load the XRawfile2_x64.dll, the program returns "could Not load library". When I compile, VS returns the following.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Loader, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Source.cpp
1>  Loader.vcxproj -> C:\Nathan\C++\Loader\Debug\Loader.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The DLL that I created is as follows. 
The Header -

```
#ifndef EVENODD_H_
#define EVENODD_H_
#include <string>
class EvenOdd
{
public:
    std::string CheckEvenOdd(const int iNum);
};

#endif //EVENODD_H_
```

The source file -

```
#include "EvenOdd.h"

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) std::string CheckEvenOdd(const int iNum)
    {
        std::string strRes = "NULL";
        if (iNum % 2 == 0)
        {
            strRes = "The given number is Even";
        }
        else {
            strRes = "The given number is Odd";
        }

        return strRes;
    }
}
```

Given this information, how can I load the DLL files contained in the MSFileReader package?

Comment: OK Nathan, please provide us with some more info: 
1. Is you executable also a 64 bit app?
2. What runtime library are you linking to?

Comment: Also, when `LoadLibrary` function fails to load a DLL, call Win32 function `GetLastError` and see what error code it return and post it here.

Comment: Thank you, Marko. I had compiled my program as a 32-bit app. I switched to 64 and the library loads now.

Comment: You are welcome! Can you please mark my answer as accepted as a token of appreciation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default settings in Visual Studio are to build a 32 bit application. You cannot load a 64 bit DLL from a 32 bit app. Change your build configuration to target 'x64' platform. Here is how you do this:

1. Open project properties
2. Click "Configuration Manager"
3. In the column "Platform", add a new entry "x64" (copy settings from Win32 plaform configuration)